# Как получить нажатие клавиши без вывода ее в консоль

Tags: c#, .net, разработка-игр

Имею вот такую вот простенькую реализацию игры Mined Out:

Месторасположение игрока, его моделька изображена количеством мин вокруг этого игрока. При этом те места, в которых я уже был, должны быть отмечены точкой. У меня они отображаются точкой, но проблема в том, что когда игрок находится справа от точки, то получается что когда я получаю символ (W-A-S-D), он пишется в консоль, и точка стирается! Я убираю автоматически эти символы в методе Move() игрока вот так:

> ```
>         Console.SetCursorPosition(X1, Y1);
>         Console.Write(". ");
> ```

здесь сначала ставится точка там, где раньше был игрок, и справа от этой точки должен быть написан символ той кнопки, на которую я нажал (например пошел вперед - w).

Как мне вообще предотвратить вывод символов нажатых клавиш? Подскажите, пожалуйста, это мне поможет исправить очень много проблем!

```
class Game
{
    static private void StartGame()
    {

        Console.Clear();

        Bomb[] Bombs = { new Bomb(2, 3), new Bomb(2, 1), new Bomb(6, 5) };

        Field field = new Field(8, 8, Bombs, new Player_CT(4, 7, 'd'), new DefuseKit(4, 6), 0, 0);
        field.MakeField();
        while (true) // game cycle
        {
            field.player.Move();
            field.PrintPlayer();
            field.player.TakeDefuseKit(field.Kits);
            if (!field.player.DefuseBomb(field.Bombs))
                break;              

            if (field.HaveWon)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(4, field.Height + 20);
                Console.Write("You\'ve won!!!");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartGame();
        PressEnter:
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            ;
        else
            goto PressEnter;
    }
}


class Bomb
{
    int _x;
    int _y;

    public int X { get { return _x; } set { if (value > 0) _x = value; } }
    public int Y { get { return _y; } set { if (value > 0) _y = value; } }

    public Bomb(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

}

class Field
{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int X { get { return _x; } set { if (value >= 0) _x = value; } }
    int Y { get { return _y; } set { if (value >= 0) _y = value; } }

    public int _height;
    public int _width;
    public int Height { get { return _height; } private set { _height = value; } }
    public int Width { get { return _width; } private set { _width = value; } }

    public bool HaveWon { get { return player.X == Width / 2 && player.Y == Y; } }

    internal Bomb[] _bombs;
    internal Bomb[] Bombs { get { return _bombs; } set { _bombs = value; } }

    internal DefuseKit Kits;

    public Player_CT player;

    public Field(int Height, int Width, Bomb[] Bombs, Player_CT player, DefuseKit DefuseKits, int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        this.Bombs = Bombs;
        this.Height = Height; // Y -- start, Y + Height -- end
        this.Width = Width; // X -- start, X + Width -- end
        this.player = player;
        this.Kits = DefuseKits;
    }

    public void MakeField()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        for (int i = 0; i <= Width; i++)
        {
            if (i == Width / 2)
            {
                Console.Write(' ');
                continue;
            }
            else
                Console.Write('-');
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        for (int i = 1; i <= Height; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine('|');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= Width; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('-');
        }
        /*for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Bombs[i].X, Bombs[i].Y);
            Console.Write('B');
        }*/
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Kits.X, Kits.Y);
        Console.Write('D');
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.Write('P');

    }

    public int BombsNearTo(int x, int y)
    {
        if (Bombs == null)
            return 0;
        int Count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Bombs[i] == null)
                continue;
            if (Math.Abs(x - Bombs[i].X) <= 1 && Math.Abs(y - Bombs[i].Y) <= 1 && (x != Bombs[i].X || y != Bombs[i].Y))
                Count++;
        }
        return Count;
    }

    public bool IsOver()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Bombs[i] != null)
            {
                if (player.X == Bombs[i].X && player.Y == Bombs[i].Y)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Height + 50);
                    Console.WriteLine("You\'ve lost!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void PrintPlayer()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.Write(BombsNearTo(player.X, player.Y));
    }

    public string this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Bombs[i].X == x && Bombs[i].Y == y)
                {
                    return "Bomb";
                }
            }

            if (Kits.X == x && Kits.Y == y)
                return "Kits";

            if (player.X == x && player.Y == y)
            {
                return "Player";
            }
            else
                return "empty point";
        }
    }

}

class Player_CT : Player
{
    public Player_CT(int x, int y, char d) : base(x, y, d) { }
    bool DefuseKits; // defuse the bomb with defuse kits - 5 seconds, without - 10 seconds
    int _hp = 100;
    int hp { get { return _hp; } set { if (value > -1 && value < 101) _hp = value; } } // hp range = (0, 100)

    public bool DefuseBomb(Bomb[] bombs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!(bombs[i] == null))
            {
                if (X - bombs[i].X == 0 && Y - bombs[i].Y == 0) // находится там где бомба
                {
                    if (DefuseKits)
                    {
                        bombs[i] = null; // bomb doesnt exist anymore
                        DefuseKits = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 30);
                        Console.Write("You\'ve lost!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void TakeDefuseKit(DefuseKit Kits)
    {
        if (Kits.X == X && Kits.Y == Y)
            DefuseKits = true;
    }



}

class DefuseKit
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public DefuseKit(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}


abstract class Player
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public char _direct;
    public char direct
    {
        get
        {
            return _direct;
        }
        set
        {
            _direct = value;
        }
    }

    public Player(int x, int y, char d)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        direct = d;
    }
    public void Move()
    {
        int X1 = X;
        int Y1 = Y;

        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var command = Console.ReadKey().Key;

            switch (command)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    Y--;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    Y++;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    X++;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.A:
                    X--;
                    break;
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(X1, Y1);
            Console.Write(". ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.ReadKey(false) вообще ничего не поменяло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.ReadKey(bool) принимает значение, нужно ли перехватывать нажатие кнопки. Если вы передадите true, то нажатая кнопка будет перехвачена и не будет выведена в консоль, что вам и нужно.